# When is a conversation started on Facebook? - NodeJS SDK

Tags: node.js, facebook, botframework

When a facebook messenger user start a conversation I want to get the data like name, photo, etc ... and send to my API.

But I'm doubtful when I should do this.

It would be in the:

```
bot.on('conversationUpdate', (session) => {
     // On here??
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Facebook doesn't support the `conversationUpdate` event. It won't send events when you start a conversation, however you could solve your issue in two different ways.

- Create a custom middleware that checks if you already have the userData from Facebook and retrieve it when you don't have it yet.
- Create a custom middleware that translates Facebook's callbacks to intents

I already created those for NodeJS, which you can use in your bot. [BotBuilder-FacebookExtensions](https://github.com/iMicknl/BotBuilder-FacebookExtension)

If you need more guidance, you can read the blogs I wrote about this:
[How to retrieve User Data from Facebook](https://imick.nl/how-to-retrieve-user-data-from-facebook-using-the-microsoft-bot-framework/) /
[How to process Facebook Messenger callbacks](https://imick.nl/how-to-handle-referrals-optins-postbacks-on-facebook-using-microsoft-bot-framework/)